# Shortcut keys for full-screen mode in Rubymine (4.x+ or 5.x+) for Windows?

Tags: view, keyboard-shortcuts, fullscreen, rubymine, shortcut

I'm using Rubymine 5.4 for Windows (the **best Ruby IDE** I've found by far, BTW).

I've discovered that you can enter full-screen mode by navigating to:

> *file menu*  >>  **VIEW** >>  **ENTER FULL SCREEN**

Once in full-screen mode, moving your mouse to the top of the screen triggers the menu bar to dropdown, where you can once again navigate to:

> *file menu*  >>  **VIEW** >>  (now changed to) **EXIT FULL SCREEN**

Does anyone know of a shortcut for this on Windows?  I think there is one for OSX - not sure what it is off-hand, but can't find anyone anywhere for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default shortcut for this action, but you can [easily add one](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/6440/20130417145554.png) in `Settings` | `Keymap`.